# multer - req.file is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm creating an app using Node, Express and multer for uploading images. I submitted the form but, req.file was undefined. I've spent the entire day troubleshooting but can't figure out what is wrong.

**FORM**

```
  <form method="get" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="upload_div"><input type="file" name="imgFile" id="image_input" accept="image/*" onchange="readURL(input)"></div>
    <div id="upload_div"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Name" placeholder="Name"></div>
    <div id="upload_div"><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div>
  </form>
```

**ROUTER**

```
...
const multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dset: '/images' });
...
router.post('/upload_processing', upload.single('imgFile'), function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.files); // result : undefiend
  console.log(req.file);  // result : undefiend
  console.log(req.body);  // result : {imgFile:"test.png", name:"test"}
  res.send(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the name you have given and the name you have used below. 
Try something like this, might help you

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'),function (req, res){  
    res.json({file: req.file})
    res.redirect('/');
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering. but, I already fixed it and now it works well. I modified "const upload = multer({dest: "/uploads' });" to "const upload = multer({dest: "uploads/"});. I still don't know why it worng. but I'm happy now!!

Comment: Either `res.json` or `res.redirect`. can't send both.